# php insert mysql_query get id

Tags: php, html, mysql

In PHP 4, how can I easily get the last `id` after an `insert` in db?
For example:

```
$queryInsert = "INSERT INTO `table` (`id`, `info`) VALUES (NULL, '".$INFO_VAR."');";

mysql_query($queryInsert) or die (mysql_error());
```

Comment: Do you really mean *Php 4*?

Comment: https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-insert-id.php

Comment: Worth having a read - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php.

Comment: Use `$insert_id= mysql_insert_id();`

Comment: Yes I know :( Php4....
Ok perfect, mysql_insert_id() returned the last value generated by auto-increment... But how can I be sure this id will be the one concerned by my insert? I mean, is it possible to have to insert by two different users at the same time (or very very closed) Which will return for both of them the same last id... (the newest one)?

Comment: No need of name and regards in the question.

Comment: If you're running PHP 4 on a production server you've got some huge problems. This is a security risk that's alarmingly severe, *especially* because you probably have an untold number of high-risk [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/).

Comment: However, it looks better to use mysqli since this one is newer and my is deprecated :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use `mysql_insert_id();`, you find [the doc here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-insert-id.php)

Comment: But how can I be sure this value is the one related to my last insert? Can it be the one auto-generated by another user just after my insertion?

Comment: No, if you read the documentation, you'll see that this is specific for each connection with the mysql server, so no other user may interfere with you. You can use it safely

Comment: Thank you very much

Comment: You are welcome, if the answer helped you please accept it! have a nice day!